# Android release build is not equivalent to debug build

Tags: android, build, proguard, release, android-app-bundle

I'm working on an android app which works just fine on debugging, while throwing different kinds of exceptions and misfunctions on release build, and again, works fine with debug version.
Proguard rules are OK. I set the debug and release buildTypes exactly like each other.

Even tried `minifyEnabled false` to no avail.

Here's a sample exception thrown by release build on some random device:

```
(1) no such table: a in "UPDATE a SET f=?,g=? WHERE id = 1"
2023-09-18 09:58:47.181 21120-21120 AndroidRuntime          com.gheyas.account  D  Shutting down VM
2023-09-18 09:58:47.182 21120-21120 AndroidRuntime          com.gheyas.account  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.gheyas.account, PID: 21120
  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.gheyas.account/e5.t7}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2071)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1729)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5511)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5469)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5855)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5808)
    at forms.Splash.H1(Unknown Source:15)
    at forms.Splash.d1(Unknown Source:0)
    at forms.Splash$e.onFinish(Unknown Source:16)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7701)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

Manifest entries are OK as well.

The question is
What differs between a release and a debug build except minifying, obfuscating and signing which may cause something like this?